# onClick with RelativeLayout is not working in Fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, onclick

Im learning coding android apps, but i ran into this issue. The onClick is not doing anything, and i dont know might be the issue. Please help

```
HomeFragment.kt
class HomeFragment:Fragment(com.advmusic.R.layout.fragment_home) {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val smh : View =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val recently_played_1 : RelativeLayout = smh.findViewById(R.id.recently_played_1)
        recently_played_1.setClickable(true)

        recently_played_1.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(activity, "This is my Toast  message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }

fragment_home.xml
<RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/recently_played_shape"
                        android:id="@+id/recently_played_1"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp">
```

Comment: Have you tried to make the layout clickable in xml?
```android:clickable="true"```

Comment: Yes, i did, In Kotlin and in xml. I didnt worked tho

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of using this in HomeFragment.kt i coded this on fragment create in MainActivity.kt

when(it.itemId){

```
            R.id.bottom_nav_home_button-> {
                val view = findViewById<View>(R.id.main_fragment_container) as FrameLayout
                val smh = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, view)
                val recently_played_title = smh.findViewById(R.id.recently_played_title) as RelativeLayout

                recently_played_title.setOnClickListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

}}